# Unable to setup SharePoint Content Database Size Monitor

Tags: solution-package, codeplex

I have deployed this WSP from http://sphealthdbsize.codeplex.com/ on my SharePoint 2010 farm.

As per documentation, I should get **Review Database Sizes** link under **Central Admin** -> **Application Management** -> **Databases**.

But there is no such link available.

Am I missing any step here?

Comment: Is Internet Explorer started by "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Yes, I even tried that now.  But no luck. Get-SPSolution is showing me the solution with Deployed=True status. (OS - Windows 2008 R2 with SP1, Single-server Farm)

Comment: Have you installed the solution? Install-SpSolution